# Cartesian product of more than two sets

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

[Here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/CartesianProduct.html) you see how to produce a cartesian product of two sets.  How can we obtain the cartesian product of three or more sets? `CartesianProduct[l1,l2,l3]` doesn't work.

Comment: `Flatten /@ CartesianProduct[CartesianProduct[list1, list2], list 3]`?

Comment: Have you seen `Tuples[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Of course! `Tuples[{S, S, S}]` did the trick. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @JM said, use `Tuples[{set1, set2, set3, ...}]`.

`CartiesianProduct` is part of the obsolete and underdocumented Combinatorica package. Try to avoid this package unless you cannot find some functionality elsewhere.

If set1, set2 are lists the example look like the following:

```
In: Tuples[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]

Out: {{a, c}, {a, d}, {b, c}, {b, d}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `Distribute`:

```
cpF = Distribute[{##}, List] &;

cpF[{a, b}, {u, v}, {r, s, t}]
```

> {{a, u, r}, {a, u, s}, {a, u, t},
>         {a, v, r}, {a, v, s}, {a, v, t},
>         {b, u, r}, {b, u, s}, {b, u, t},
>         {b, v, r}, {b, v, s}, {b, v, t}}